# Resolve all conflicts and rerun the merge to apply the remaining In autoated Merge Script

Tags: svn

We have a automated batch Script which takes care of merge and outputs all the log (conflicts) in a text file for developers to get proper visibility. 
Now the problem is sometimes it stops in between and gives the below error
**svn: E155015: One or more conflicts were produced while merging  Resolve all conflicts and rerun the merge to apply the remaining In autoated Merge Script** 
Below is the command

svn merge  http://xyzBranch.local.com C:\WORKSPACE\Trunk\ --username=xyz--password=zyz --non-interactive >> C:\mergelogs\logs

Any help would be appreciated I tried a lot of ways to fix this but no success

Regards
Pravin

Comment: I've never heard of anybody having an automatically merging script for subversion and I don't see how such thing would be used. If you explain how you _use_ the script, perhaps we can give you more specific advice what to do in this case. So far I can only try to explain when it happens (which I tried below).

Comment: I meet the same error using TortoiseSVN v 1.12 when merging multiple revisions and conflict at one of the revisions: after conflict resolving Subversion stops the merge and I have to run merge again. The biggest pain is to collect merge revisions again --> have to backup them. As I remember before (with TortoiseSVN v 1.8) in similar situations after conflict resolving the merge was continued. But I think that's not TortoiseSVN fault --> my fault, possibly.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when some of the commits were already "cherry-picked", i.e. merged using the `-r x:y` flag. In such case subversion first merges everything up to `x` and than everything above `y`. If merging `x` fails, it gives this error.

I don't think you should be working around it. If you want to do the merge, just do it manually. If you don't, just tell the script to stop trying.

Answer (score -1):

I would try adding the parameters:

```
--accept=postpone
```

I use this for running `svn merge` and what it will do is add conflict markers to the files, but should always return. I'm surprised that the `--non-interactive` flag doesn't do this automatically though.  The other thing to try is amend the redirection to include `2>&1` which will also redirect standard error, in case there's a warning that isn't being caught in the log file.  So your new command becomes:

```
svn merge http://xyzBranch.local.com C:\WORKSPACE\Trunk\ --username=xyz--password=zyz --non-interactive --accept=postpone >> C:\mergelogs\logs 2>&1
```

Comment: The command already _has_ `--accept=postpone`. The `--non-interactive` flag does add it. This happens when skipping cherry-picked revisions and `--accept=postpone` does not help. -1, does not answer the question.

Comment: Even when done manually through tortoise client i get the above error.The merge stops in between even if its non-interactive. the scripts main command is the one which i posted earlier rather then that i use cleanup,update the local workspace and then merge. Is it due to the fact the branch is not mergered with mainline for a long time.Solution might be helpful.

Comment: Please let know when and why the below error come svn: E155015: One or more conflicts were produced while merging Resolve all conflicts and rerun the merge to apply